# What values are valid in Pandas 'Freq' tags?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, frequency

I am trying to use `date_range`. I came across some values valid for `freq`, like `BME` and `BMS` and I would like to be able to quickly look up the proper strings to get what I want.

What values are valid in Pandas 'Freq' tags?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You can find it called [Offset Aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

> A number of string aliases are given to useful common time series frequencies. We will refer to these aliases as offset aliases.

```
Alias    Description
B        business day frequency
C        custom business day frequency
D        calendar day frequency
W        weekly frequency
M        month end frequency
SM       semi-month end frequency (15th and end of month)
BM       business month end frequency
CBM      custom business month end frequency
MS       month start frequency
SMS      semi-month start frequency (1st and 15th)
BMS      business month start frequency
CBMS     custom business month start frequency
Q        quarter end frequency
BQ       business quarter end frequency
QS       quarter start frequency
BQS      business quarter start frequency
A, Y     year end frequency
BA, BY   business year end frequency
AS, YS   year start frequency
BAS, BYS business year start frequency
BH       business hour frequency
H        hourly frequency
T, min   minutely frequency
S        secondly frequency
L, ms    milliseconds
U, us    microseconds
N        nanoseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

###### How to find offset aliases

You can find the entire list of valid frequencies by

```py
pd.offsets.__all__
```

which returns

```
['BusinessDay', 'MonthBegin', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second', ...]
```

It turns out each of these is a class and all of them have a `_prefix` attribute which is the alias. So, e.g., the alias of `Minute` can be found by

```py
pd.offsets.Minute._prefix        # 'T'

# some other aliases
pd.offsets.MonthEnd._prefix      # 'M'
pd.offsets.MonthBegin._prefix    # 'MS'
```

In fact, if we look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx#L3925-L3960), the alias dict is constructed by accessing `_prefix` of each offset class.

###### Anchored offsets

In addition to the offsets in [jezrael's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35339226/19123103), you can also specify an [anchoring suffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) for some frequencies.

Weekly frequencies can have anchors on any day of the week: `W-SUN`, `W-MON`, `W-TUE`, `W-WED`, `W-THU`, `W-FRI` and `W-SAT`.

For example, to anchor weeks to end on Mondays, you can use `W-MON` (note that it is case-insensitive).

```py
pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', freq='w-mon')
# DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-03', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-17', '2022-01-24', '2022-01-31'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='W-MON')
```

Also quarterly and annual frequencies can have anchors on any month of the year; i.e. the following frequencies can have month as a suffix so that each frequency can be anchored to end on that month:

- `Q`
- `QS`
- `BQ`
- `BQS`
- `A`
- `AS`
- `BA`
- `BAS`

and the valid suffixes are `JAN`, `FEB`, `MAR`, `APR`, `MAY`, `JUN`, `JUL`, `AUG`, `SEP`, `OCT`, `NOV` and `DEC`.

For example, to anchor years to end at the beginning of May, you can use `A-MAY`

```py
pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2023-02-01', freq='AS-May')
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-01', '2021-05-01', '2022-05-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='AS-MAY')
```