# 1 Year Rolling mean pandas on column date

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation, rolling-average

I would like to compute the 1-year rolling average for each row in this Dataframe `test`:

```
index   id      date        variation
2313    7034    2018-03-14  4.139148e-06
2314    7034    2018-03-13  4.953194e-07
2315    7034    2018-03-12  2.854749e-06
2316    7034    2018-03-09  3.907458e-06
2317    7034    2018-03-08  1.662412e-06
2318    7034    2018-03-07  1.346433e-06
2319    7034    2018-03-06  8.731700e-06
2320    7034    2018-03-05  7.145597e-06
2321    7034    2018-03-02  4.893283e-06
...
```

For example, I would need to calculate:

- mean of variation of id `7034` between 2018-03-14 and 2017-08-14
- mean of variation of id `7034` between 2018-03-13 and 2017-08-13
- etc.

I tried:

```
test.groupby(['id','date'])['variation'].rolling(window=1,freq='Y',on='date').mean()
```

but I got the error message:

```
ValueError: invalid on specified as date, must be a column (if DataFrame) or None
```

How can I use the pandas `rolling()` function in this case?

---

**[EDIT 1]** [thanks to Sacul]

I tested:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.set_index('date').groupby('id').rolling(window=1, freq='Y').mean()['variation']
```

But `freq='Y'` doesn't work (I got: `ValueError: Invalid frequency: Y`) Then I used `window = 365, freq = 'D'`.

But there is another issue: because there are never 365 consecutive dates for each combined `id-date`, the result is always empty. Even if there missing dates, I would like to ignore them and consider all dates between the current date and the (current date - 365) to compute the rolling mean. For instance, imagine I have:

```
index   id      date        variation
2313    7034    2018-03-14  4.139148e-06
2314    7034    2018-03-13  4.953194e-07
2315    7034    2017-03-13  2.854749e-06
```

Then,

- for 7034 2018-03-14: I would like to compute MEAN(4.139148e-06,4.953194e-07, 2.854749e-06)
- for 7034 2018-03-13: I would like to compute also MEAN(4.139148e-06,4.953194e-07, 2.854749e-06)

How can I do that?

---

**[EDIT 2]**

Finally I used the formula below to calculate rolling median, averages and standard deviation on 1 Year by ignoring missing values:

```
pd.rolling_median(df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['variation'],window=365, freq='D',min_periods=1)

pd.rolling_mean(df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['variation'],window=365, freq='D',min_periods=1)

pd.rolling_std(df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['variation'],window=365, freq='D',min_periods=1)
```

Comment: Well formatted, shows an attempt, explicitly gives the error. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this should work for you:

```
# First make sure that `date` is a datetime object:

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.set_index('date').groupby('id').rolling(window=1, freq='A').mean()['variation']
```

using `pd.DataFrame.rolling` with datetime works well when the `date` is the index, which is why I used `df.set_index('date')` (as can be seen in one of the [documentation's examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html))

I can't really test if it works on the year's average on your example dataframe, as there is only one year and only one ID, but it should work.

## Arguably Better Solution:

**[EDIT]** As pointed out by Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu, `freq` is now a deprecated argument. Here is an alternative (and probably more future-proof) way to do what you're looking for:

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('id')['variation'].resample('A').mean()
```

You can take a look at the [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html#pandas.Series.resample) documentation for more details on how this works, and [this link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) regarding the frequency arguments.

Comment: `ValueError: Invalid frequency: Y`

Comment: It might be related to the fact that `freq` is deprecated. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: It's strange, it works for me. based on [this link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases), does it work when you try using frequency `'A'`? Should do the same thing.

Comment: `A` works fine. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: `0.21.1`. Glad it works. It seems maybe in older versions, `'A'` is the only accepted alias for year end frequency ([as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35339226/6671176)), but the current [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) includes `'A'` and `'Y'` as aliases.

Comment: I'm on version 0.22.0

Comment: Then I'm at a loss :\

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set your date as the index:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.index = df['date']
```

Then, the easiest way to define you window is to use a string using one of the [offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
df.groupby('id').rolling('365D')['variation'].mean()
```

Alternatively, for more flexibility, you can also use a timedelta:

```
from datetime import timedelta
one_year = timedelta(days=365)
df.groupby('id').rolling(one_year)['variation'].mean()
```