# How to efficiently do a sum over the previous year for many rows in a dataframe grouping by an ID column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which is a series of rows containing identifiers of individuals, dates of their appointments and a numerical value.

For every row, I need the sum of the numerical values for that individual over the past year. I effectively want to do:

```
df.groupby('ID')['numerical value'].cumsum()
```

but I want the `cumsum` to include only rows where the date is up to a year in the past.

I'm currently using the following apply function but it is very slow when I have a long dataframe.

```py
def sum_hist(appt_date,personID,key):
    search_limit=appt_date+pd.Timedelta("-365 days")
    temp_df=df[(df["ID number"]==personID)
    & (df["Appointment Date"]>search_limit) & (df["Appointment Date"]<=appt_date)]
    return(sum(temp_df[key].values))

df[key]=df[["Appointment Date","ID number"]].apply(lambda x: sum_hist(*x,key),axis=1)
```

I'd appreciate any method to do that same thing that is more efficient.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388065/1-year-rolling-mean-pandas-on-column-date

Comment: Thanks @SH-SF, that more or less solves it for me. I will edit my question as soon as I can get my grouped results back into dataframe.

Comment: Consider creating an answer (and not putting your answer in the question). This way visitors see if there is an answer in list overviews on stackoverflow.

Comment: @ilmiacs will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this can be achieved with the pandas rolling function:

```py
df.groupby('ID number').rolling(window='365d',min_periods=1,on="Appointment Date")['numerical value'].sum()
```

It greatly improves the speed and makes my problem possible to run in less than a minute rather than the hours it was taking previously.

Thanks @SH-SF for the link to [1 Year Rolling mean pandas on column date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388065/1-year-rolling-mean-pandas-on-column-date)