# Creating pandas series with all 1 values

Tags: pandas, date-range

I'm trying to generate a pandas timeseries where all values are 1.

```
start=str(timeseries.index[0].round('S'))
end=str(timeseries.index[-1].round('S'))

empty_series_index = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='2m')
empty_series_values = 1
empty_series = pd.Series(data=empty_series_values, index=empty_series_index)

print(start,end)
print(empty_series)
```

The printout reads

```
2019-09-20 00:30:51+00:00 2019-10-30 23:57:35+00:00

2019-09-30 00:30:51+00:00    1
```

Why is there only one value, even tough its a 2min frequency and its more than 10 days long?

Comment: `freq='2min'` (or `'2T'`) not `'2m'`, which is interpreted as 2 months.

Comment: that's it and can be marked as answer

Comment: I don't know that I could really add anything more than is already stated in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339139/where-is-the-documentation-on-pandas-freq-tags. These are often mixed up because `pd.to_datetime` uses  '%M'  for the Minute formatting and '`%m'` for month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the line:
`empty_series_index = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='2m')`
you are using the frequency string: `'2m'` which actually means 2 months.

If you want to use minutes you should use: `'2min'` or `'2T'` (from [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases))

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any more questions.