# How to generate ends of periods with pandas date_range?

Tags: python, pandas, date, date-range

I want to generate the dates of periodic transactions, which is possible with pandas `date_range`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

d1 = date(2023,11,1)
d2 = date(2026,5,1)
period_length = '12M'
pd.date_range(start = d1, end = d2, freq = period_length)

# Output:
DatetimeIndex(['2023-11-30', '2024-11-30', '2025-11-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='12M')
```

My issue is that the transactions should occur at the end of the periods, i.e. the first date should be 31.10.2024. I can in fact generate the expected result adding a date-offset, but that requires to convert the frequency-string (which is not always 12 months) to an explicit timedelta:

```
pd.date_range(start = d1 + pd.DateOffset(months = 12, days = -1), end = d2, freq = period_length)

# expected Output:
DatetimeIndex(['2024-10-31', '2025-10-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='12M')
```

Is there a way to either

1. tell `date_range` to generate the ends of periods or
2. use the same frequency-string in `date_range` and `DateOffset`?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Can't you just subtract one day from `start` and then drop the first generated value?

Comment: As far as I know, if you want a custom frequency like `'12M'` to behave the way you want, your method is the way to go. However, `12M` is also annual, so in this specific case, you can use `period_length = 'A-OCT'` instead (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75281182/19123103) to read more about anchors).

Comment: @cottontail you should probably post that as an answer, or close as a dupe

Comment: @Nick I would but I don't have the python dupe hammer.

Comment: Better answer then! :) It doesn't seem that there are a lot of questions on this topic.

Comment: I don't agree that my question is a duplicate, as the starting date is not necessarily in November and thus the`'A-OCT`-solution doesn't solve the general problem (and none of the other strings neither, I checked them all beforehand). Dropping the first value however does, and I'm ashamed I wouldn't find it on my own...
This being said, I would love to see `OffDate` and `date_range` converge towards the same inputs, as both methods have strenghs and weaknesses.
Thanks for your help!